# How to handle $dispatch and $broadcast deprecations in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource, vue-component, vue-router

I was working on a large-scale Vue.js application, and I have used `broadcast` and `dispatch` tons of places in my application. What's the best way to sit down and change all these? Or do I have some other way to deal with these breaking-changes?

Comment: You will need to change your codebase, cause it's a major version upgrade and major upgrades tend to contain _incompatible API changes_ according to semver.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both these methods now are merged in the `$emit` method.

Unfortunately, replacing every instance of `$broadcast` and
`$dispatch` with `$emit` will not work because the pattern
used to manage events the one of the 'event emitter' now.

In my opinion the quickest way to deal with this deprecation is to create a spurious Vue instance and use it as an event hub.

Comment: That I know, so basically there's no way besides changing my *old* codes?

Comment: It's the hard truth.

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the same issue as you since I used a lot $broadcast and $dispatch. The solutions are:

- as the previous answer points out, using a component as an event hub for managing your app state;
- using vuex. I took some time to analyse the options and really felt that vuex was the way to go. Vuex provides you a central structure to manage all your app state and event and provides great out-of-box utilities that you can easily bring to your components. It also makes the code more modular and easier to rearrange and work with. At least in my opinion. I started using it 2 weeks ago and I'm really thrilled with it. If you take the time to learn I think it may be worth.

Cheers

Comment: I am a bit reluctant when it comes to vuex. I have read about it. it's actually my second option at the moment. 

Event hub isn't more or less the same as State Management though? Except this time I'll be using $emit instead  of $broadcast and $dispatch

Comment: Well, I don't know what kind of needs your app has and although you can do state management like it was pointed out before if your app is to grow, you may want have a more solid structure that can support it. At least from my point of view and I'm not that experienced but... I can only say that I was kind of reluctant also before trying but now I can really see the benefits for my projects. It's just another option :)

Comment: Think I might need to give Vuex a try then!

Comment: Go for it, then you can see what is the best fit for your needs. Cheers

Comment: If you are to use vuex 2.0 that's still in rc you may find this link (https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/releases) useful

Comment: Thanks i'll take a look. I'm pretty sure i'll move to Vuex though ;) thanks!